# running android application java error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an android application and when run it in android studio , it comes with this error msg as shown , any suggestion to solve that ?

[image]

Comment: Check your directories

Comment: Thank you @Frank N. Stein  . I check my directories , I imported and I was able to check everything in there but can not to run . It is in my download folder with the name GameSurvey-2 .

Comment: Thank you @lukassz  . I check my directories , I imported and I was able to check everything in there but can not to run . It is in my download folder with the name GameSurvey-2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that android studio is expecting a 'production' directory/folder.

Try creating the folder under your top level directory and then a clean rebuild (project - clean, the project build).

I suspect you (or a library you are using) has changed the default output locations in the gradle build file as i dont remember 'production' being a output dir (usually debug or release).

Comment: Thank you @DEzra . I have tried to put a folder named production and inside it my project ,  but not work the same . I will try clean rebuild

Comment: I did rebuild project and nothing happen it still the same error , any suggestion ? Thank you

Comment: hi @algisy123, is the GameSurvey created from android studio or have you download it from  net? can you paste your build.gradle file to question? as this would help debug.

Comment: yes it is work now @DEzra , the problem was with the output folder , I have changed from project structure to a new one and works correctly but with some warnings . I will check for the warnings . Thanks

Comment: @algisy123 Glad to help.